# Return array of replacements from ruby

Tags: ruby, string-substitution

I want to take the string `foofoofoo`, map `foo` to `bar`, and return all individual replacements as an array - `['barfoofoo', 'foobarfoo', 'foofoobar']`

This is the best I have:

```
require 'pp'
def replace(string, pattern, replacement)
  results = []
  string.length.times do |idx|
    match_index = (Regexp.new(pattern) =~ string[idx..-1])
    next unless match_index
    match_index = idx + match_index
    prefix = ''
    if match_index > 0
      prefix = string[0..match_index - 1]
    end

    suffix = ''
    if match_index < string.length - pattern.length - 1
      suffix = string[match_index + pattern.length..-1]
    end

    results << prefix + replacement + suffix
  end
  results.uniq
end

pp replace("foofoofoo", 'foo', 'bar')
```

This works (at least for this test case), but seems too verbose and hacky. Can I do better, perhaps by using `string#gsub` with a block or some such?

Comment: I don't think Ruby provides such functionality out of the box.

Comment: @JaredBeck Just to clarify, the input string is given as an example - the real problem is to support arbitrary strings, and replace matches by pattern at any index with the provided replacement. So, for instance, `replace('foofof', 'f|o|fo', 'x')` should yield `['xoofof', 'xofof', 'fxofof', 'fxxfof', 'foxfof', <etc.>]`

Comment: Please update you question according to your last comment. Also, `'f|o|fo'` is a string, not a pattern. You should use `/f|o|fo/` if you want a pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to do with `pre_match` (`` $` ``) and `post_match` (`$'`):

```
    def replace_matches(str, re, repl)
      return enum_for(:replace_matches, str, re, repl) unless block_given?
      str.scan(re) do
        yield "#$`#{repl}#$'"
      end
    end

    str = "foofoofoo"

    # block usage
    replace_matches(str, /foo/, "bar") { |x| puts x }

    # enum usage
    puts replace_matches(str, /foo/, "bar").to_a
```

EDIT: If you have overlapping matches, then it becomes harder, as regular expressions aren't really equipped to deal with it. So you can do it like this:

```
def replace_matches(str, re, repl)
  return enum_for(:replace_matches, str, re, repl) unless block_given?
  re = /(?=(?<pattern>#{re}))/
  str.scan(re) do
    pattern_start = $~.begin(0)
    pattern_end = pattern_start + $~[:pattern].length
    yield str[0 ... pattern_start] + repl + str[pattern_end .. -1]
  end
end

str = "oooo"
replace_matches(str, /oo/, "x") { |x| puts x }
```

Here we abuse positive lookahead, which are 0-width, so we can get overlapping matches. However, we also need to know how many characters we matched, which we can't do as before now that match is 0-width, so we'll make a new capture of the contents of the lookahead, and calculate the new width from that.

(Disclaimer: it will still only match once per character; if you want to consider multiple possibilities at each character, like in your `/f|o|fo/` case, it complicates things yet more.)

EDIT: A bit of a tweak and we can even support proper gsub-like behaviour:

```
def replace_matches(str, re, repl)
  return enum_for(:replace_matches, str, re, repl) unless block_given?
  new_re = /(?=(?<pattern>#{re}))/
  str.scan(new_re) do
    pattern_start = $~.begin(0)
    pattern_end = pattern_start + $~[:pattern].length
    new_repl = str[pattern_start ... pattern_end].gsub(re, repl)
    yield str[0 ... pattern_start] + new_repl + str[pattern_end .. -1]
  end
end

str = "abcd"
replace_matches(str, /(?<first>\w)(?<second>\w)/, '\k<second>\k<first>').to_a
# => ["bacd", "acbd", "abdc"]
```

(Disclaimer: the last snippet can't handle cases where the pattern uses lookbehind or lookahead to check outside the match region.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Ruby provides such a functionality out of the box. However, here's my two cents, which may be more elegant:

```
def replace(str, pattern, replacement)
  count = str.scan(pattern).count
  fragments = str.split(pattern, -1)

  count.times.map do |occurrence|
    fragments[0..occurrence].join(pattern)
      .concat(replacement)
      .concat(fragments[(occurrence+1)..count].to_a.join(pattern))
  end
end
```

Comment: This is  a really good approach for the problem as stated. See my comment under my question - I actually need to support matches that may happen starting at any index, so, for instance, `replace('oooo', 'oo', 'x')` should return `['xoo', 'oxo', 'oox']`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to take the string foofoofoo, map foo to bar, and return all individual replacements as an array - ['barfoofoo', 'foobarfoo', 'foofoobar']

If we assume that the input is always exactly "foofoofoo" (three "foo"s), then the problem is trivial, so let's assume there are one or more "foo"s.

```
def possibilities(input)
  n = input.length / 3
  n.times.map { |i| 
    (['bar'] + Array.new(n - 1, 'foo')).rotate(-i).join 
  }
end

possibilities "foo"
# ["bar"]
possibilities "foofoo"
# ["barfoo", "foobar"]
possibilities "foofoofoo"
# ["barfoofoo", "foobarfoo", "foofoobar"]
```

There are solutions that would use less memory, but this one seems convenient.